# how to set default value for string variable in groovy

Tags: groovy, jenkins-groovy

I have the following function defined in groovy

```
def deploy_app(Map InputParameters, List OptionalParameters = []) {
    String InputParametersString = InputParameters.inject([]) { acc, val -> acc + "--set ${val.getKey()}=${val.getValue()}" }.join(" ")
    .
    .
    .
}
```

What i want to do is be able to have the map `InputParameters` parameter to have default value of empty map AND also for the string `InputParametersString` to have a default value of empty string if `InputParameters` parameter is not passed or is empty.

Here is what i have tried using **elvis operator** but not working

```
def deploy_app(Map InputParameters = [:], List OptionalParameters = []) {
    String InputParametersString = "" ?: InputParameters.inject([]) { acc, val -> acc + "--set ${val.getKey()}=${val.getValue()}" }.join(" ")
    .
    .
    .
}
```

also tried this

```
def deploy_app(Map InputParameters = [:], List OptionalParameters = []) {
    String InputParametersString = InputParameters.inject([]) { acc, val -> acc + "--set ${val.getKey()}=${val.getValue()}" }.join(" ") ?: ""
    .
    .
    .
}
```

So how do i do this so that when no `InputParameters` is passed, i am able to have the string `InputParametersString` as empty string value?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
def deploy_app(Map InputParameters=[:], List OptionalParameters = []) {
    String InputParametersString = InputParameters.inject([]) { acc, val -> acc + "--set ${val.getKey()}=${val.getValue()}" }.join(" ")
}


def r = deploy_app()

assert r instanceof String
assert r.length()==0
```

the `InputParametersString` evaluated to empty string correctly if input map is empty

Comment: is this correct way to set default empty Map value? `Map InputParameters = [:]` in parameters?

Comment: edited answer. and yes - `[:]` is correct for empty map

Comment: you changed your answer? i think old answer is preferred because i did not paste full function..i posted just part of it and only added the part that i can just replace in-place...can you paste your old answer at the top..instead of deleting it..just paste on top of this one

Comment: i want to say that your code works fine and to define default map value use `[:]`

Comment: did you see my previous comment? you removed your previous answer..can you repost that answer?